# If check box changes from FALSE to TRUE, then all formulas in that same Row are replaced with its calculated results

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

If any cell on column A changes from FALSE to TRUE, then all the existing formulas on that row will be replaced with its calculated values.

when I tick the checkbox to TRUE, it means I don't need more calculations or formulas on that row, all I need is the final calculated values.

in my screenshot the formula in column D is =B3+C3, I want to replace the formula with the calculated result, which is 2

See the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIGW6.png)

[image]

I Looked everywhere, cannot find a script for this, please help.

Comment: Can you clarify, do you mean that if any cell in that column changes, or a certain series of cells change values? I apologize but your question is very ambiguous and it is hard to discern what you want. Please clarify and we will be happy to help.

Comment: Hi thanks, here is an example: 

If the value of any cell from column A is changed to TRUE (for example, cell A2 value changed from FALSE to TRUE) Then replace all the formulas applied in row number 2 with values.

Comment: What values would you like to put when the cell in the row changes its state to TRUE?

Comment: when cell is TRUE, i want to automatically remove all formulas in that particular row, by replacing them with the results of the formulas only (the values)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  //e.source.toast('Entry')
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='*********Enter Your Sheet Name***********'){return;}
  //e.source.toast('Flag0');
  if(e.range.columnStart==1 && e.value=='TRUE') {
    //e.source.toast('Flag1');
    var rg=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn());
    var vA=rg.getDisplayValues()[0];
    var fA=rg.getFormulas()[0];
    //Logger.log('vA: %s fA: %s',vA,fA);
    fA.forEach(function(f,i) {
      if(f && e.range.columnStart!=i+1) {
        e.range.offset(0,i+1-e.range.columnStart).setValue(vA[i]);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: It got this error: ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment (line 4, file "Code.gs")

Comment: another error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (line 12, file "Code.gs")

Comment: Okay.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Now TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 2, file "Code")

Comment: You can't run this with out the onEdit trigger event object.

Comment: So give it the sheet name you want it to run for and then goto that sheet and make edits with checkboxes I presume in column 1.  Originally, I thought it was column 2 but then I realized it's column 1

Comment: Hi Cooper, thanks so much for helping out, i followed the instructions but nothing seems to change when i edit with checkboxes, either in column 1 or column 2

Comment: the formulas are still not being replaced with its values

Comment: If you can provide an image what your spreadsheet looks like and I’ll test it.

Comment: I attached image

Comment: Okay thanks for that image that helps to confirm what I thought

Comment: Thanks so Much to Cooper, it works perfectly! exactly what I needed :)

Comment: Hi Cooper, the script works perfectly as expected, but the values are formatted, for example, if the result of the formula is $2, i want to get only the unformated value, which is 2.

Comment: how do i get the value only, instead of the displayed value?

Comment: Try using getValues(); instead of getDisplayValues();